# ASP.Net MVC3 SessionState timeout

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-timeout

I have it set to 120 minutes but it doesn't last that long. I am not sure exactly how long it does last but I know it isn't 2 hrs.

```
<sessionState timeout="120" />
```

This was set only in the default Web.config and NOT in the one in the Views directory nor the Web.Debug.config or Web.Release.config.

Would that make a difference as the default session timeout is 20 min?

Comment: Your application pool recycling would kill the sessions too.

Comment: @JonathanWood _session state is generally not recommended for ASP.NET_ - do you have some more information on this?

Comment: @Darren - How can I tell if the application pool is killing the session?

Comment: @JonathanWood - Are you saying that there should be a static variable for the "Customer Number" of the currently signed in customer, as opposed to using the SessionState ? I know it's been .. quite awhile since you posted that, but is that still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee your sessions don't get killed by a w3wp.exe crash or an application pool recycle, you should move the session state to a separate store. The easiest is the ASP.Net State Server service. Make sure to start the service on the host machine and add this to your web.config instead:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
    cookieless="false"
    timeout="120"/>
```

Comment: I will have to talk to my network admin about this. I'm only the developer.

Comment: @MB34: It can also be done with a SQL server. Keep in mind, that anything you put into session this way must implement the `Serializable` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should define the session state mode**

There are there different session states in ASP.NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=VS.80).aspx

**In-Process Mode**
The defaul one is `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10" />`, the session will be clear after rebuild the project

**State Server Mode**
we can use this, but remember to turn the services - ASP.NET State Service

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
  sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=sa;Password=12345678; Integrated Security=SSPI"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="2"
/>
```

**SQL Server Mode** we can use this after create a DB ASPSate by command, pls check this site for details - http://www.brianstevenson.com/blog/aspstate-concurrently-running-for-net-1011-and-net-20

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:63586"
  sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=sa;Password=12345678; Integrated Security=SSPI"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="2"
/>
```

The session in State Server Mode & SQL Server Mode will not be cleared after rebuild the project, it's good for development